# Facebook dialog fails and stops the activity

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, native-activity

I'm using the Facebook SDK on Android to post an update to the user's feed. I was able to get it to work when I did not have the Facebook client installed. Now, even after removing the Facebook app, when I try to authorize or open the feed dialog the activity is abrupty killed.

I don't get any message telling me that the app has crashed or anything. It's just destroyed. The only message is Mono telling me that the thread 0x0 has been prematurely finalized, which is odd. Also, there's this odd "Not supported in this case." message from webcore.

I'm using the NativeActivity class. I don't use it directly but I extend it in my activity. Here's the logcat from around where things go wrong:

```
I/PixelWorldEngine( 6796): Authorizing for Facebook...

D/Database( 6796): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.ri.BubblingUpLite/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, error message: No such file or directory

D/Database( 6796): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.ri.BubblingUpLite/databases/webview.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 35 M, handle: 0x801450

D/Database( 6796): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.ri.BubblingUpLite/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, error message: No such file or directory

D/Database( 6796): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.ri.BubblingUpLite/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 35 M, handle: 0x7ff128

D/skia    ( 6796): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin

W/webcore ( 6796): Not supported in this case.

I/PixelWorld-glue( 6796): WindowFocusChanged: 0x333288 -- 0

D/SensorService(  120): disable: connection.get() = 0x9f5c20

D/SensorService(  120): disable: get sensor name = BMA150 3-axis Accelerometer

D/SensorService(  120): SensorDevice::activate: handle = 0x0, enabled = 0x0

D/Sensors (  120): Enable akm: en = 0

D/SensorService(  120): noteStopSensor: uid = 0x274d, handle = 0x0

D/SensorService(  120): pid=6796, uid=10061

D/SensorService(  120): Active sensors:

D/SensorService(  120): CM3602 Light sensor (handle=0x00000004, connections=1)

W/webcore ( 6796): Not supported in this case.

W/mono    ( 6796): Thread 0x0 may have been prematurely finalized

D/SensorGUI(  120): ~SensorChannel: mSendFd = 255, mReceiveFd = -1

D/AudioPolicyService(   72): stopOutput() tid 2223

D/AudioPolicyService(   72): releaseOutput() tid 2223

D/AudioPolicyService(   72): releaseOutput() tid 2223

I/ActivityManager(  120): Process com.ri.BubblingUpLite (pid 6796) has died.

I/WindowManager(  120): WIN DEATH: Window{407e9548 com.ri.BubblingUpLite/com.ri.PixelWorldEngine.GameActivity paused=false}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an Android bug which seems to manifest on HTC devices.
See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33612